# Vscode not reading in my default value and telling me theres no value typed in

Tags: django, migration

Below is my code where I try to make 0 as a default if no information is added into my admin. I am confused because my error "ValueError: Field 'asking_price' expected a number but got ' '." is telling me I have put in no information when I try to make my migrations.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0DiF.png)

Comment: Did you mistakenly put a default for the field as `default=' '` previously? If you did you would need to either delete the migration file for that or edit it yourself. Please show the _full_ stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: `default=0.0`.

Comment: This sadly did not work. I am still receiving ValueError: Field 'asking_price' expected a number but got ' '. After putting default=0.0 instead of just default=0